# Replicating ArcMap legend in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, grouping

I am trying to replicate this ArcMap legend in QGIS but i can't seem to get it right.

[image]

I am stuck in print layout and using QGIS 3. I have the title 'LEGEND' but i do not know how to categorize the legend items exactly this way(with headers). For example, i would like to classify 4 legend items under a category FTF. Ultimately, i would like to have 3 categories and then select the legend items to go under each of them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am stuck in print layout and using QGIS 3. I have the title 'LEGEND' but i do not know how to categorize the legend items exactly this way(with headers). For example, i would like to classify 4 legend items under a category FTF. Ultimately, i would like to have 3 categories and then select the legend items to go under each of them. I would like to send a screenshot of what i have now but i am not sure of how to upload another image here.

Comment: Okay, i have just added the second image, thank you. Can you advise how i can make the second look like the first?

Comment: Hello, can you add the layer tree you use ? Every icon is one layer with categories or rules for styling or each is in different layers ?  The way to work with will have some differences.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uncheck "auto update"
2. Click on "add group"
3. Mark the group and click on "edit selected item properties"
4. Enter the name you want and go back
5. Select the items you want in the group and move them into the group via drag&drop
6. Adjust spacing, font size, columns, and everything you need

[image]

Exampleresult:

[image]

*You could also do the grouping outside your legend on your main map.*

Comment: I have previously taken all the steps you highlighted and the only issue is that the drag and drop doesn't work. Rather than it dragging, it just highlights all the legend items and it doesn't pull into the created group.

Comment: See that GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpxhn.gif Hold CTRL while selecting the items.

Comment: For some reason, it just doesn't work in my layout, it still the same behaviour after holding down CTRL and selecting the items. It just copies all and doesn't drag them

Comment: Are you working with QGIS 3.16?

Comment: Can i send you a link to look at my live screen and help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

To build on @MrXsquared's answer,

- In your map window, duplicate your layer 4 times.
- Hide your main layer.
- In duplicate layer #1, only show the EGE symbols. Do this by removing all the other symbols in the layer symbology.

[image]

- In duplicate layer #2, only show the HAT symbols.

[image]

- In duplicate layer #3, only show the Humanitarian Assistance symbol.

[image]

- In duplicate layer #4, only show the remaining HPN symbols.

[image]

- Then in your composer layout, group and display the layers as @MrXsquared suggests.